# how to create a multi-color text string that changes colors periodically (like las vegas banners)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a banner/title for a page that is multi-color - and also changes those colors every 10 seconds (based on a config value)

I have the following fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Mv4pw/21/) that gives a multi-color text using jquery. I don't know how to make the colors change every few seconds. it would be ok to cycle through the colors specified in the colors variable.

I am trying to see how to update the text (say every 10 seconds) so that the colors in the text change - like the banners in Las Vegas ?

**JavaScript code**

```
    var colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "blue", "brown"],
        idx;

    $(function () {
        $('.rainbow').html(function (_, html) {
            var ret = $([]);
            $.each(html.split(''), function (_, letter) {
                var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
                var span = $('<span />', {
                    text: letter,
                    css: {
                        color: colours[idx]
                    }
                });
                ret = ret.add(span);
            });
            return ret;
        });
    });
```

**html code**

```
 <div class="rainbow"> ..... some text here .... </div>
```

jsfilddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mv4pw/21/

thanks for any updates.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "blue", "brown"];
var title = "See Live Monkeys";
var interval = 10000;

function randomizeTextColor() {
    $(".rainbow").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        var color = colors[Math.floor(colors.length * Math.random())];
        var letter = $("<span>", {
            text: title.charAt(i),
            css: {
                color: color
            }
        });
        $(".rainbow").append(letter);
    }
}

$(randomizeTextColor);

window.setInterval(randomizeTextColor, interval);
```

**REVISED CODE**

```
var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "blue", "brown"];
var interval = 500;

function randomizeTextColor(element) {
    var text = $(element).text();
    $(element).empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var color = colors[Math.floor(colors.length * Math.random())];
        var letter = $("<span>", {
            text: text.charAt(i),
            css: {
                color: color
            }
        });
        $(element).append(letter);
    }
}

function randomize(selector) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
        randomizeTextColor(this);
    });
}

$(randomize(".rainbow"));
window.setInterval(function() { randomize(".rainbow") }, interval);
```

Comment: But this method does not allow me to use the class multiple times ? And the string is hard coded ?  How can I retain the flexibility and get the function.  Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the revised code I added and see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: works like a charm.. thanks - set the time to a short time - and it's like blinking lights.. set it longer - and you have nice dynamic content.

Comment: Yeah, I had a lot of fun playing around with the interval setting while working on this. If you change the interval variable to 25 and the color variable to `"#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);` it gets really trippy!