# Change color of certain bars of same dataset periodically Chartjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to change the color of two bars every five bars of the same dataset on my bar chartjs chart.

*I want something like: Red Red Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Red Red Blue...*

Currently I have the following code:

```
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'dataset1',
            fill: false,
            // i want this to be red 2 times every 5 bars
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,204,100)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255,204,100)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(156,94,0)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgb(156,94,0)',
            data: data
        } ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
        //more code...
    }
});
```

Comment: i think this will helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110443/how-to-create-a-multi-color-text-string-that-changes-colors-periodically-like-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set `backgroundColor` as an array of colors with the same length as your bar graph data.

For example:

```js
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red'],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [-3, 30, -10, 33, -9, 14, -11],
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```